# Odd flute behavior

Tags: flute

I am very new to flute, but I have played various instruments over the years.  A thing I am having issues with is when I go from the fingering for G4 to the fingering for A4 (according to all the fingering charts I have seen), it actually jumps to something closer to B-flat.  Do I just suck right now, or is something odd going on with my flute?

Comment: It shouldn't sound like that so I am wondering if your Bb key is maybe a bit sticky?

Comment: @Jomiddnz A sticking B-flat key will not affect an A.

Comment: Yes, either you are doing something wrong or your flute is not working properly. Or maybe both. Without seeing your flute and/or hearing you play we have no way of telling what the problem is.

Comment: @PiedPiper thanks for the information.  I was just trying to solicit some advice before taking it in.  Just seemed like something odd was happening.  It sounded odd to my ear and when I went to the tuner, it was showing it as almost a semitone off for the A fingering but was pretty much right on for the G fingering.  I'll take it into my local shop and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities here, but you’re probably not going to get a definitive answer without standing in front of a more experienced flautist and showing them.

- as @Jomiddnz suggests, perhaps your Bb key is stiff
- the padding on your B or A key may be leaking
- you may be subconsciously tightening your embouchure  in an effort to ‘make’ the higher note
- you may be subconsciously changing the horizontal angle of the flute against your lip, or rolling it inwards
- you may be touching a key further down the flute, perhaps on your right hand, to steady the flute as your left hand has less contact

Or it could be a combination of more than one of the above, or something else I’ve not thought of!

Comment: If the Bb key is stiff that's not going to affect the A at all. If a pad is leaking that will affect the G more so than the A. If OP is touching keys farther down the flute that will *lower* the pitch rather than raise it. Tightening the embouchure or turning the flute in, is unlikely to raise the pitch almost a semitone.

Comment: Could it be that the G4 is actually closer to an F# and the A is an A?